# Changing the axis xmax/domain in a step plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Consider the MWE below. This example is from the PGF Plot galery with added 1 outlier (1000,50) resulting in the first (wrong) screenshot below.

I want to limit the domain/axis, so I get something like the second screenshot **but with the (1000,50) coordinate still in the source.**

I tried changing axis and plot domain (and adding axis label):

```
\begin{axis}[ymin=0,ymax=1,xmin=0,xmax=1,thick,xlabel=x,ylabel=y]
```

and:

```
\addplot+[domain=0:1,...
```

This does not work for this type of plots. However this is work for other plots (e.g. function plots). How can I get this working?

[image]
[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[black,const plot,mark=none]
coordinates
{(0,0.1)    (0.1,0.15)  (0.2,0.5)   (0.3,0.62)
 (0.4,0.56) (0.5,0.58)  (0.6,0.65)  (0.7,0.6)
 (0.8,0.58) (0.9,0.55)  (1,0.52) (1000,50) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

When setting `xmin=0, xmax=1` in your example, I get a `dimension too large` error. This happens because the point `1000,50` is still processed, even though it lies outside the visible axis domain, and causes an overflow error. To fix this, set `restrict x to domain=0:1`. That key specifies that points with x coordinates outside the specified range are filtered out without any further processing:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=1, restrict x to domain=0:1]
\addplot+[black,const plot,mark=none]
coordinates
{(0,0.1)    (0.1,0.15)  (0.2,0.5)   (0.3,0.62)
 (0.4,0.56) (0.5,0.58)  (0.6,0.65)  (0.7,0.6)
 (0.8,0.58) (0.9,0.55)  (1,0.52) (1000,50) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```